# Multiple Workers to run parallel-ly in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker

I have created a Worker Service project in .NET Core with the intention of 3 independent workers. All these 3 workers should run parallel-ly and independent of other workers. And this worker service as a whole will be running as a Windows Service.

In the main Program.cs, I have registered the 3 workers as below:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                    services.AddHostedService<WorkerA>();
                    services.AddHostedService<WorkerB>();
                    services.AddHostedService<WorkerC>();
                });
    }
```

Each worker code will be as follows, doing their intended job:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
          WorkerA_DoWork();
          await Task.Delay(6000, stoppingToken);
     }
}
```

**Problem Statement:** When I execute the project, I am facing few issues like, when WorkerA() doesn't have any process to run, WorkerB() (or) WorkerC() do not start their work. I think it is basically waiting for WorkerA() to do something before WorkerB() or WorkerC() can start doing their work.

Please advise how can they work independently i.e.: each workers should not wait for other worker and should run independently.

Comment: If your workers job is not related one to another, why don't you split them in to different services? In this scenario, you also have better service isolation, if one worker goes down the rest are still working. In your case if WorkerA throws an exception the whole service is down.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! I was thinking your solution as the last option. Just want to see if there is an option available.

Answer (score 3):

> When I execute the project, I am facing few issues like, when WorkerA() doesn't have any process to run, WorkerB() (or) WorkerC() do not start their work. I think it is basically waiting for WorkerA() to do something before WorkerB() or WorkerC() can start doing their work.

.NET Core allows any number of hosted services; however, it *starts* executing them serially. So the problem with this code:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    WorkerA_DoWork();
    await Task.Delay(6000, stoppingToken);
  }
}
```

is that `WorkerA_DoWork` is synchronous. I.e., it's synchronously waiting for work to do.

The solution can be one of two things. Either make the "get next work item" method asynchronous:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    await WorkerA_DoWorkAsync();
    await Task.Delay(6000, stoppingToken);
  }
}
```

or wrap the entire `ExecuteAsync` inside a `Task.Run`:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () =>
{
  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    WorkerA_DoWork();
    await Task.Delay(6000, stoppingToken);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wrapped my workers inside a Task.Run worked! Thanks @Stephen Cleary!

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: Which of the two solutions should we prefer? Would we gain any performance / parallelism boost when choosing solution two with `Task.Run`? Is there any advantage, because we run the task on the thread pool? In my use case, I have multiple hosted services dispatching messages from various sources such as Azure Service Bus queues or database tables. Each hosted service is responsible for different data "channels" and different domain logic parts (within the same BC).

Comment: @Joerg: The `Task.Run` usage in my answer is not about parallelism; it's about [not blocking app startup](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html). I always include the `Task.Run` in my services for that reason.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, I understand the original problem and how your answer solves it. My question was about ADDITIONAL benefits from either of the two alternative solutions. Apart from removing the blocking issue, does the second solution ALSO yield better performance when the worker does CPU-heavy work?

Comment: @Joerg: No, it does not.

Comment: @StephenCleary thank you. Could you elaborated on this, please? Is the background service instance already started on a separate pool thread behind the scenes? I am just asking because [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work) says: "If the work you have is I/O-bound, use async and await without Task.Run. If the work you have is CPU-bound, use async and await, but spawn off the work on another thread with Task.Run."

Comment: @Joerg: No, it's not started on a separate thread pool thread ([yet](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063#issuecomment-518913079)). The article you linked to is about writing asynchronous code in general; `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync` is a very specialized case due to how it's invoked by the runtime.

Comment: @StephenCleary You wrote that a) your second solution does not have any additional benefits for CPU-bound work and b) that the background service instance is not started on a separate thread pool thread. Are statements a) and b) taken together not a contradiction to what the article says in general? Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Joerg: I think our comments are getting pretty far from the original question. Why don't you ask your own question?

Comment: @StephenCleary I started to do that and then found out what my mistake was. Maybe it helps others, too, so I will quickly share it here: The crucial point is how to make the synchronous `WorkerA_DoWork` asynchronous in solution A. That probably only works by calling `Task.Run` somewhere inside `WorkerA_DoWorkAsync`. And then, of course, solution A and solution B are equivalent with both solutions running their work on a thread pool thread. That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly in .net Core you just can initialize 1 HostedService, which mean that only the first inyected will run in background. A fiable solution is to create a HostedService Wrapper, that initizalices your classes:

```
public class Orchestrator: IHostedService
{
    private readonly WorkerA _workerA;
    private readonly WorkerB _workerB;

    public Orchestrator(WorkerA workerA, WorkerB workerB)
    {
        _workerA = workerA;
        _workerB = workerB;
    }
    #endregion

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await _workerA.StartAsync(cancellationToken));
        Task.Run(async () => await _workerB.StartAsync(cancellationToken));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(StartAsync(cancellationToken));
    }
}
```